# How to create an image gallery on an Alfresco WQS site?

Tags: alfresco, image-gallery

I am creating a basic CMS website using Alfresco Web Quick Start.

I want to have an image gallery on my site whereby all the images in my galleries folder are displayed like a standard gallery (i.e. click to move smoothly to next image, click on image to enlarge, possibly add a comment).

I currently have my images on a gallery page of the site but you must click on each of the thumbnails to enlarge and return to the main gallery page before you can view another image. It is functional but doesn't look good so I need to improve this!

I thought this add on may have been a possible solution (http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/gallery-plus-dashlet) but it only displays the images on the site dashboard but I want to have my gallery included within the Gallery page of my site. Any assistance at all with this would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check is what version of Alfresco you are using. DeckShare was designed and built around Alfresco 3.3 (If I remember correctly). It most likely will not work correctly with newer versions of Alfresco, i.e. 4.0, as some code has changed in the core product.

Since you are new to Alfresco, the easiest thing to do would be to install an older version of Alfresco. If you are more ambitious, you could try and update the DeckShare code to work with a newer version.

I think I have accomplished something similar to what you want using Lightbox (SlimBox rather). I did a short presentation on WQS which included a LightBox integration (see page 27) http://www.tribloom.com/content/tale-two-wqs-implementations-pdf for an example. I believe WQS pages already include slimbox.js in which case it is very easy to create a component/web script to display a gallery (mine is called imagebrowser.get.html.ftl):

```
...
    <div class="interior-content">
        <#if articles.assets?size == 0>
            ${msg('list.none')}
        <#else>
            <#if subTitle??><h3>${msg(subTitle)}</h3></#if>                
            <ul class="portfolio-wrapper"><#list articles.assets as article><li><a href="<@makeurl asset=article />${linkParam!''}" rel="lightbox-img" title="${article.title!''}"><img src="<@makeurl asset=article rendition='rightColumn'/>" alt="${asset.title!''}" class="img-border" /></a></li></#list>
            </ul>
        </#if>
    </div>
...
```

Comment: Also, the Slimbox web site offers usage examples: http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox#usage

Comment: Thanks v much for your reply! Unfortunately I am using Alfresco 4.0, the path in programming doesn't often run smoothly :) I had a quick look at the gallery examples and they look great. (I actually came across that presentation when I was researching my image gallery options). I don't 100% understand how you mean I should get this started, a little clarification would be great. Thanks so much  :)

Comment: Also will I be able to incorporate a SlimBox gallery into the existing work I have been doing on my WQS site? Thanks again.

Comment: Got this sorted! Just have to fix a few glitches with the image thumbnails. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-deckshare/) is a project that uses WQS to build a site for sharing presentations. One of the features it includes is a carousel of images. The images included are preview images of the presentations stored in the Alfresco repo. You should be able to take that component and do something similar to implement an image gallery in your own WQS-based site.

Comment: Hi @JeffPotts, thanks for the reply! I'm new to Alfresco so your help is really appreciated. That sounds great. Quick question about deployment. I am manually deploying the files to my Alfresco installation, I understand that the deckshare-wcmqs files should go in the Alfresco/tomcat/webapps directory but where should the files from the deckshare-share and deckshare-repo be copied to?

Comment: deckshare-share is meant to be deployed to the share.war. deckshare-repo is meant to be deployed to the alfresco.war. Both of those projects have Ant build files, so assuming your build.properties is set properly, you should be able to run ant deploy for each project and the files will go where they belong.

Comment: Hi @JeffPotts, I followed your advice on deploying the deckshare files (thanks again). But when I start Alfresco I get the following error in the stdout log file and the home page to my site is unable to be rendered. 
`11:26:01,923 ERROR[org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService] Unable to process template: five-block
11:26:01,923 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService] An exception occurred while rendering: homepage`


Your help is really appreciated! I need to get this completed asap, frustration is beginning to set in :(

Comment: **UPDATE** Have resolved the above problem. But I have the following error when I start Alfresco after deploying the deckshare-wcmqs files.  `14:30:43,103 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerMappings' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/surf-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmisSessionInterceptor' while setting bean property 'interceptors' with key [1];` Thanks